# indexing with decimal numbers: applications

Tags: r, indexing, decimal

My question is less a coding problem than a matter of mere curiosity. One nice thing in R is that indexing rules are quite flexible, since we can:
 index with positive integers, ranges, negative integers (removing rows/columns), index with partial column or row names, etc.

If I understand the usefulness of the these possibilities, the fact that one can index with decimal numbers makes me quite dubitative: in what situations would this be possibly useful ? Do you have examples? Shouldn't it **return an error** (it does in Matlab for instance)?

It seems to perform a `trunc` operation:

```
mtcars[22, 1:3]
####                   mpg cyl disp
#### Dodge Challenger 15.5   8  318
mtcars["Dod", sqrt(c(1, 5, 10))]
####                   mpg cyl disp
#### Dodge Challenger 15.5   8  318
```

(I couldn't find the help page for the indexation, maybe it's all explained in detail..)

Thanks,

Comment: `?Extract`  "Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards zero)". In what use case this could be useful? I would like to know, too.

Comment: `?'['` contains all you need to know, including conversion of numeric to integer.

Comment: Oh ok! that was a tricky one... but still, any idea on the interest of such a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Indices are numeric or character vectors or empty (missing) or NULL.
>   Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence
>   truncated towards zero).

You ask:

> in what situations would this be possibly useful ? Do you have
>   examples?

That's a very open-ended question. Let me give one example. Let's assume you have a matrix and want to extract all columns corresponding to indices that are square numbers. The `^` function is documented to return a numeric vector, i.e., a double. However, luckily subsetting accepts these as indices.

```
typeof((1:10)^2)
#[1] "double"

m <- matrix(1:1e3, nrow = 10)
m[, (1:10)^2]
#works
```

Also note that you can use `m[, 1]` instead of `m[, 1L]`.

In general, this behavior is convenient (but sometimes dangerous) if you compute indices. Of course, it could also be more strict and force you to coerce indices to integer explicitly, but the creators of R decided in favor of convenience. You are expected to use your own checks if you compute indices and floating point precision could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Roland, your exemple is a good one. i understand that this behavior could be useful for big matrices where the column number is analogous to a distance measure, something like that. Maybe in image processing also...

Comment: @agenis This behavior saves you from always making indices integers. Be happy that you don't have to type the `L` all the time.